# OSX 10.11.x and Adobe CS6 suite incl photoshop?

Tags: macos, adobe-photoshop

Since updating to OSX 10.11.3, I have found Photoshop CS6 will not load, as well as several other programs. Others include Hugin, possibly Dragon Dictate 5 (not resolved or confirmed yet re VP updating), Bamboo digital tablet, and a few others.

Concentrating on Photoshop CS6, for me following upgrading to OSX 10.11.3 it begins to load then freezes. A web search (several done over a few months) seems to suggest for others there is no issue, yet for others there is, and for some few if any of the CS6 suite is working. Adobe no longer offers support for CS6. Apple is silent.

I am left confused if there are few or many that find Photoshop CS6 working fine on OSX 10.11.x. If here are many, perhaps a recent replacement of the motherboard, CPU/GPU is the real issue, not OSX 10.11.x in my case.

I understand OSX 10.11 relocated some system files as part of improved security, so it could be the issue. Others posts on other sites seemed originally to confirm this.

This article seems to outline these changes best:  [Article Security Changes OSX 10.11.x](http://www.infoworld.com/article/2988096/mac-os-x/sorry-unix-fans-os-x-el-capitan-kills-root.html)

Lost and confused.

Comment: When you upgraded to El Capitan, did you do a clean install or just upgrade in place?  I did a clean installation and installed CS 6 with no problem.

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by clean, vs in place install. I did not wipe the HD and begin from scratch. I did update via App Store application. Good to know Photoshop CS6 working for someone on OSX 10.11.x. Suggest the issue may well be local to my laptop/setup/installation. I have not done a clean install of the CS6 suite as it seemed many others (initially) were reporting the issues after upgrade of OSX. That seems to have changed somewhat since.

Comment: Clean install as in *wipe the HD*.  I always recommend backing up via Time Machine, wipe and install the new OS, install software from scratch then migrate data and settings over from Time Machine.  It's highly unlikely that your issues are because of hardware.

Comment: Ta appreciate your responses. First constructive thoughtful response gained in 4 months. Thanks mate.

Comment: No problem.  Do a clean install and let me know how it works out.

Comment: Thanks. Will not be have time to do this for awhile. However, you have confirmed that CS6 incl Photoshop is not inherently broken on OSX10.11.x. That explains why there were others reporting same as me, but not the outcry I expected. Also a clean install of the CS6 suite may also resolve the issue. Such has not worked with Dragon Dictate or Hugin. Knowing there is a solution means as soon as I get the time I will work on it to resolve. Very helpful.

Comment: Did you get the prompt to install Java? CS6 depends on it. Upgrading Mac OS removes Java. You need to reinstall Java.

Comment: Yes, Java installed. Latest v8. Legacy java 6 is needed for some other programs in the CS6 suite.

Answer (score 1):

Last night I updated to OSX 10.11.6. I have made no changes to my Photoshop CS6 installation since posting this question.

With this update, Photoshop now opens and loads perfectly fine. I have not done any complex operations, but it works fine. Seems the Apple Feedback site may get read after all.

This may be of interest to other Mac Users with issues with Photoshop CS6.

Comment: Some months after posting answer, Photoshop, After Effects all still working fine, and without backdating to legacy java 6.